# PHP How to query information needed from 3 tables in one select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 3 tables:

users table(PK user_id)

> Fields: user_id, user_first_name,
>   user_last_name, username,
>   user_email...etc

pals table (FK user1_id, user2_id from PK user_id in users table)

> ```
> pal_id    user1_id    user2_id          status        timestamp
> 7           98              97               0     2011-02-02 21:44:28
> 8           92              98               1     2011-02-04 08:06:00
> 9           95              92               0     2011-02-04 08:05:54
> 10         97              92               1     2011-02-04 08:05:28
> 11         97              95               1     2011-02-04 08:06:33
> ```

picture table (FK user_id from PK user_id in users table)

```
picture_id  picture_url             picture_thumb_url               user_id  avatar         timestamp
73      ../User_Images/66983.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/66983.jpg     92     0    2011-02-03 21:52:02
74      ../User_Images/56012.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/56012.jpg     92     0    2011-01-25 12:09:58
75      ../User_Images/58206.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/58206.jpg     95     0    2011-01-22 22:12:35
76      ../User_Images/85428.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/85428.jpg     98     0    2011-01-23 23:50:16
77      ../User_Images/42325.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/42325.jpg     98     0    2011-01-24 00:11:15
78      ../User_Images/73154.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/73154.jpg     98     1    2011-01-24 00:11:15
81      ../User_Images/92865.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/92865.jpg     92     0    2011-01-31 18:24:34
82      ../User_Images/75611.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/75611.jpg     92     0    2011-01-26 18:08:52
83      ../User_Images/74829.jpg    ../User_Images/Thumbs/74829.jpg     95     0    2011-02-01 20:48:48
84      ../User_Images/5987.jpg     ../User_Images/Thumbs/5987.jpg      92     1    2011-02-03 21:52:02
```

I am making a social networking site where I want to have a user's pals shown in a PHP generated table. I want to show pal thumbnails and other information below these thumbnails so that if you click on a thumbnail, it takes you to that user's profile.

From above, user 92 is pals with user 98 because they have confirmed friendship(shown as status = '1')

user1_id in the pals gets the user id of the initiator of the friendship. For pal_id=8, user 92 requested friendship, 95 confirmed it. Had user 95 requested friendship and it had been confirmed, user2_id would be reading 92. User 92 has another pal, user 97. 97 initiated the friendship.

Users can have pictures, stored in the picture table above. A user selects his avatar from his pictures...that is done by setting one of his picture.avatar = '1'.

Now, how will I make my PHP query to show pal thumbnails and info?

I have this so far(my desired results are way off!)

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connections.php'); ?>
<?php
//query username
$user_id = $_SESSION['UserSession'];
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
mysql_select_db($database_connections, $connections);
$query_user_info = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$user_info = mysql_query($query_user_info, $connections) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_info);

bla bla bla

<?php
while ($pal_no = mysql_fetch_assoc($pal_no_result))
{
    //get pal info
    $query_pal_info = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN pals ON (pals.user1_id = users.user_id) OR (users.user_id = pals.user2_id) 
    INNER JOIN picture ON picture.user_id = users.user_id AND picture.avatar = '1' WHERE users.user_id = '$user_id'";
    $pal_info = mysql_query($query_pal_info , $connections) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_pal_info = mysql_num_rows($pal_info);

    //echo table with pal information
    echo "\n<table>";
    $j = 5;
    while ($row_pal_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($pal_info))
    {
        if($j==5) echo "\n\t<tr>";
        $thumbnail_user = $row_pal_info['picture_thumb_url'] != '' ? $row_pal_info['picture_thumb_url'] : '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png';
        echo "<td width='100' height='100' align='center' valign='middle'><a href = 'user_view.php?user_id2={$row_pal_info['user_id']}'>
        <img src='/NNL/User_Images/$thumbnail_user' border='0'/></a></td>\n";
        $j--;
        if($j==0) {
        echo "\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>";
        $j = 5;
        } 
    }
    if($j!=5) echo "\n\t\t<td colspan=\"$j\"></td>\n\t</tr>";
    echo "\n</table>";
}
?>
```

Ze problem iz here:

```
$query_pal_info = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN pals ON (pals.user1_id = users.user_id) OR (users.user_id = pals.user2_id) 
    INNER JOIN picture ON picture.user_id = users.user_id AND picture.avatar = '1' WHERE users.user_id = '$user_id'";
```

How do I fix it? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: if you are still having problem then you can mail me your database export sql file

Comment: @experimentX. Maybe I have redundant info in my database. You have an email address I can send it to?

Comment: well send email at santoshlinkha@hotmail.com

Comment: but i am not sure i wil be able to reply today since it's 8 pm here and i am still in office

Comment: @experimentX. It is sent. Please reply when you have the time. Thanks and good weekend

Comment: Well i have replied and there's nothing with the two avatars for user id 92 .... and you project is sure big enough to give a nasty headache

Comment: And I am goin offline for 13 hrs

Comment: Lol. I have been getting headaches. Ill Get back to you later.

Comment: okay i have checked you php code too and i have the final answer see updates ....!

Comment: @Kinyanjui i have replied back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is my final answer! And this is working perfectly!!**

```
class MySQLDatabase{
    private  $hostname = 'localhost';
    private  $username = 'root';
    private  $password = 'password';
    private  $dbname = 'test';
    private $result;

    private $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect()   
    {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
        if (!$this->connection)
            die(mysql_error());         

        if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbname))
            die(mysql_error());
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        if(!$this->connection)
            $this->connect();
        $this->result = mysql_query($sql);      
        if(!$this->result)
            die(mysql_error());
        return $this->result; 
    }

    public function numOfRows()
    {
        return mysql_num_rows($this->result);
    }

    public function fetchArray($resultset)
    {
        return  mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset);
    }
}

$mysqldb = new MySQLDatabase();

$userid = 92;


$sql1 = "SELECT pals.user2_id AS pals_id1, users.user_first_name AS pals_first_name, ".
    " users.user_last_name AS pals_last_name, picture.picture_thumb_url AS ".
    "  picure, picture.avatar AS avatar FROM pals INNER JOIN (users LEFT JOIN picture ".
    " on picture.user_id = users.user_id) ON users.user_id = pals.user2_id WHERE pals.user1_id".
    " =".$userid." AND picture.avatar = 1 GROUP BY pals_id1;";

$palinfo1 = $mysqldb->query($sql1);


$sql2 = "SELECT pals.user1_id AS pals_id1, users.user_first_name AS pals_first_name, ".
    " users.user_last_name AS pals_last_name, picture.picture_thumb_url AS picure, picture.avatar".
    " AS avatar FROM pals INNER JOIN (users LEFT JOIN picture on picture.user_id = users.user_id)".
    " ON users.user_id = pals.user2_id WHERE pals.user2_id = ".$userid." AND picture.avatar = 1 GROUP BY pals_id1;";
$palinfo2 = $mysqldb->query($sql2);


echo "<table>";

while($palinfo = $mysqldb->fetchArray($palinfo1)){
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($palinfo as $info => $value){
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

while($palinfo = $mysqldb->fetchArray($palinfo2))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($palinfo as $info => $value){
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";
```

And also you need at least two queries to display all friend list. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply experimentX. I'll get back to you

Comment: ok. "SELECT pals.*, user_id AS user_id, users.user AS username, picture.picture AS picture
 FROM users INNER JOIN (pals LEFT JOIN picture ON pals.user2_id = picture.userid) ON
 user_id = pals.user1_id";............i get: Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @Kinyanjui Kamau  okay user1 i pal is our user an user2 is the pal of our user (so we are selecting pal's photo from picure) okay will update answer please check

Comment: when i try: "SELECT pals.*, users.user_id AS user_id, users.user_id AS username, picture.picture_id AS picture
 FROM users INNER JOIN (pals LEFT JOIN picture ON pals.user2_id = picture.user_id) ON
 users.user_id = pals.user1_id";.......i get:Notice: Undefined index: picture_thumb_url in C:\wamp\www\NNL\pals.php on line 130 many times

Comment: I did not define the 3 tables properly: users, pals and picture

Comment: Okay let me make you clear

In user table we have our user

In pal table, we have our user' pal

So join inner join user and pal (on pal user1_id) that way we will fetch all user user's pal

Because user1_id is our hero

And user2_id is our hero's pal so left join to picture user id i.e. user2_id and picture user_id, In that way we will accomplish to get user's pal's picures...agreed. However the user's pal could be user1_id(pal_id = 10 above). Will this still work?

Comment: @Kinyanjui okay you forgot so select picture thumb check again update after 3 min

Comment: @Kinyanjui yes that would still work, but you need to keep in mind that what you join from user to pal (user1_id or user2_id) that is our hero

Comment: Im still working on this. Keep getting an error: "Unknown column 'users.user' in 'field list'" with: "SELECT pals.*, users.user_id AS user_id, users.user AS username, picture.picture AS picture_thumb_url FROM users INNER JOIN (pals LEFT JOIN picture 
 ON pals.user2_id = picture.userid) ON user.id = pals.user1_id";

Comment: @Kinyanjui oops! my mistake i will update final version on 5 minutes

Comment: @experimentX. Really appreciate the attention btw. I used pal.user1_id = 92. I understand the changes thought not quite there yet. The results im getting now are all the pictures of user 98 which are 3 in total, ie. his prof pic and his other two. Nothing for his other pal user 97. Where do i place the condition for pictures that avatar field = '1'. Because I need only those?

Comment: @experimentX. with: "SELECT pals.user2_id AS pal_id, users.user_first_name AS pal_first_name, users.user_last_name AS pal_last_name, picture.picture_thumb_url AS picture FROM users INNER JOIN (pals LEFT JOIN picture on picture.user_id = pals.user2_id AND picture.avatar = '1') ON users.user_id = pals.user2_id WHERE pals.user1_id = '$user_id'";.........It is good. Only Problem, no pal (user 97) for '$user_id' = 92....and it shows his avatar twice

Comment: @Kinyanjui well for first question you can add AND picture.avature = 1 at the end and for second question, and for your second question, i think you might have redundant data please again check update

Comment: Thanks. Good luck in your future projects

Comment: Oops. One more thing...please check your email